# How to store a comma separated string from Excel workbook into a PowerShell variable

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a list of values in multiple columns in the spreadsheet from an excel workbook. How do I extract those values and store them into a variable? The spreadsheet looks as follows:

```
  A          B          C

1  Col1    Col2    Col3

2  11        22        33

3  44        55        66

4  77        88        99
```

Here's the code I am using

```
$file = "C:\demo.xlsx"

$sheetName = "Sheet1"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)

$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)

$objExcel.Visible=$false

$rowCount = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
   

for ($i=2; $i -le $rowCount-1; $i++)

{

     numberList += $sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).text -join "','"

     numberList += $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).text -join "','"

     numberList += $sheet.Cells.Item($i,3).text -join "','"

}

$numberList

$objExcel.quit()
```

It's not concatenating values into single quotes & commas.
Am I using -join at the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-join` takes *a collection* of strings on the left-hand side, but in this expression:

```
$sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).text -join "','"
```

the left-hand side operand (`$sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).text`) is always going to be just *a single string*.

---

Wait with the quoting and concatenation until *after* you've collected all the cell values:

```
# enumerate all the cell values, store in $numberList
$numberList = for ($i=2; $i -le $rowCount-1; $i++)
{
    $sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).Text
    $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).Text
    $sheet.Cells.Item($i,3).Text
}

# Now we quote them ...
$numberList = $numberList |ForEach-Object { "'${_}'" }

# ... and finally join them into one big string
$numberList -join ','
```